# Skyrim on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, steam

I've been trying to get Skyrim running through Steam on Wine on Ubuntu 16.04. I've had little luck with PlayOnLinux, and opted to use Wine 2.0 and set it up myself instead. I can't get it to run fullscreen, it'll only run as a non-resizable window as in the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD3au.png) I've set bFullScreen to 1 in SkyrimPrefs.ini. Is there somehthing I'm missing? I've played 73 minutes of Skyrim and never gotten past the front page cause it won't fullscreen and I'm a little desperate. Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [WineHQ's documentation for The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=24749)?  Specifically, you could be missing the **height** and **width** settings.

Comment: Altering those values seems to have no impact on the size. I set iSize to 20000 and it's still the same. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes, but that page has other examples of full-screen issues.  Did you take a look?

Comment: I think I did something wrong while trying to alter the skyrimprefs.ini. I was building this in a VM, so I wiped and started from scratch and it works fine now. Time to do it for real. Thanks so much for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

When going Steam with PlayonLinux the ini file to use is located at `SteamLibrary/steamapps/compatdata/489830/pfx/drive_c/users/steamuser/My Documents/My Games/Skyrim Special Edition/SkyrimPrefs.ini`
where SteamLibrary is the folder where you installed the Game at.